# Can I installed tensorflow for python 2.7 and 3.5 on my machine simultaneously?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, installation, tensorflow, anaconda

Currently I have Python 2.7, Python 3.5, Tensorflow for Python 3.5 installed on my machine (MAC OX) via Anaconda. I would like to install Tensorflow for Python 2.7 on my machine as well.

When I tried "conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7", I got the following error: "*Error: prefix already exists: /Users/x644435/anaconda/envs/tensorflow*".  It must be because I have already installed tensorflow for python 3.5.

Can I installed tensorflow for python 2.7 and 3.5 on my machine simultaneously?  And how?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `-n tensorflow` names the environment "tensorflow".  Environment names have to be unique. Try  `conda create -n tensorflow27 python=2.7 tensorflow`

Comment: I tried and got the following error:  Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .
Error:  Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
  - tensorflow

Comment: tensorflow is in the conda-forge repository. If you did not add to the default channels, you have to use `-c conda-forge` as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, you can**. Create two environments *(tensorflow, tensorflow3)* -- as @cel mentioned in the comments the environment names should be unique and it is only for your reference.

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7
conda create -n tensorflow3 python=3.5
```

Now you have two environments with python2.7 and python3.5 (tensorflow is not installed yet!)

In order to do that move to each environment:

```
source activate <environment-name>
```

Then install Tensorflow in each environment based on the python that is to be used. (based on the anaconda version that you are using you can use `pip/pip3` or `conda-forge`).

If you are installing with GPU then you need to download and install the [CUDA](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads&usg=AFQjCNEfZue7HZfgQMRSvztHrvDA1ncGsA) libraries as well. Also, remember to set the environment variables in `.bashrc`

Once you are done, you can view the list of environments using the command:

```
conda info --envs
```

**SOLUTION TO YOUR SPECIFIC ERROR:**
*The error that you got is probably because you already have an enviroment with the name "**tensorflow**".* List the environments to see your existing Conda Enviroments using `conda info --envs` and then create the new `python 2.7` environment using another name enviroment name like `tensorflow27` using `conda create -n tensorflow27 python=2.7`

**NOTE**: When installing ANACONDA if you pre-appended the **CONDA** path to the PATH environment variable then change it to **post-append** (`export PATH="$PATH:/home/dennis/anaconda3/bin"`)
so that the installation doesn't override the existing python installation. (you can check this using `$which python`

**TESTED** - ***I have both versions installed on my machine***

**REFERENCE**: https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html