# Conda environment python2.7 tensorflow import error

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I have to use python2.7 only. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863377/can-i-installed-tensorflow-for-python-2-7-and-3-5-on-my-machine-simultaneously) answer and installed tensorflow using

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

After that when I import tensorflow, I get the following error stack trace

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-67f8173eef8c> in <module>()
      1 # Workspace problem with several narrow gaps
      2 
----> 3 import tensorflow as tf
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

/home/ultrainstinct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 try:

/home/ultrainstinct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 from tensorflow.python.tools import component_api_helper

/home/ultrainstinct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ultrainstinct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ultrainstinct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ultrainstinct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /home/ultrainstinct/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: invalid ELF header


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I went to the site mentioned above, but did not find anything related to this error.

How do resolve this?

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try it ,may be helpful:  `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow`